# Passing Javascript variable into textbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a variable called totalScore:

```
totalScore = '<h2>Total Score: ' + parseInt(parseFloat(scorePrompt) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt2) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt3) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt4) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt5) +
                                                        '</h2>');
```

I need to pass the number stored inside totalScore to a textbox. I have not found a way to pass a variable to an html element, sorry if I am missing something very obvious I am new to javascript.

Comment: `document.getElementById('textboxid').text="your value"` isn't a simple?

Comment: Store the number in a separate variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('txtScore').value = totalScore;
```

Comment: The number, not the generated HTML.

Comment: read my other answer below..

Answer (score 2):

to give you some background on why we do what we do:
javascript gets its hooks into html via the DOM API. this accounts for most uses of js. 
what you are trying to do is two things: add an element to the html, and insert a text node inside that element. 
one doesn't really 'pass a variable' to an html element. one can turn a variable into a string, and append that, as a text node, to the DOM. 
so you  might be looking for something like this:

```
totalScore = '<h2>Total Score: ' + parseInt(parseFloat(scorePrompt) +
parseFloat(scorePrompt2) +
parseFloat(scorePrompt3) +
parseFloat(scorePrompt4) +
parseFloat(scorePrompt5) +
'</h2>');
document.getElementById("myelementID").innerHTML = totalScore;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("id").value =your value;
```

By using this you can assign value to textbox.

Answer (score 1):

Pure JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('myTextBox').value = 'myValue';
```

jQuery:

```
$('#myTextBox').val('myValue');
```

Comment: Have you seen CodeSlayer's answer before adding yours?

Answer (score 1):

Just add this line of code

```
document.getElementById("{yourTextBoxId}").value= parseInt(parseFloat(scorePrompt) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt2) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt3) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt4) +
                                                        parseFloat(scorePrompt5);
```

just replace `{yourTextBoxId}` to id of your textbox.

By doing this you will get the number without html.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this

```
    totalScore = parseInt(parseFloat(scorePrompt) +
                    parseFloat(scorePrompt2) +
                    parseFloat(scorePrompt3) +
                    parseFloat(scorePrompt4) +
                    parseFloat(scorePrompt5);
    // if you want only number.
    document.getElemenyById('text_box_id').value = totalScore;

    // if you want number + string.
    totalScore = '<h2>Total Score: ' + totalScore + '</h2>');
    document.getElemenyById('text_box_id').value = totalScore;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery syntax

```
$('#yourTextboxID').val(totalScore)
```

or in HTML

```
document.getElementById('yourTextboxID').value=totalScore;
```

Answer (score 0):

why not try to put another variable..like this

```
var total =parseInt(parseFloat(scorePrompt) +                                                     parseFloat(scorePrompt2)+
                   parseFloat(scorePrompt3) +
                   parseFloat(scorePrompt4) +
                   parseFloat(scorePrompt5);

totalScore = '<h2>Total Score: ' + total +'</h2>';

//now you don't need to cut every character to check if it is numeric or not
document.getElementById('txtValue').value=total;
```